# Loading json file outside of wwwroot

Tags: c#, json, file, asp.net-core, loading

I store my language resource files as JSON and need to load and deserialize them using `Newtonsoft.Json` package.

It wouldn't make much sense to put these files in the `wwwroot` folder since they are not to be used or opened directly by the client.

I tried to load them using `File.LoadAllText()` but it tries to find those files in the `wwwroot` and won't look outside of that.

Is there anyway I can load them?

Comment: Did you try just using a path like `..\some.json`? You're not limited to wwwroot in any way even though it might be the working directory

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, You are right, it works. It was my understanding that you can't use or load static files outside of `wwwroot`, while you can use them but they won't be available to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access any files your environment allows even though the working directory by default is set to `wwwroot`. It makes sense to store data that is not accessed directly by the client to other directories than `wwwroot`.

You can use the services at `PlatformServices.Default.Application` to get the path to the `approot` folder via `ApplicationBasePath`. This way you can be sure you are accessing the correct files without relying on working directory and relative paths.

To use this you have to add a reference to `Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions`.